# Можно ли изменить версию php в консоли относительно папки проекта

Tags: php, linux, symlinks

На сервере есть несколько проектов, и у каждого своя версия php (где-то 8, 7.3 і т.д.), и у некоторых проектов есть консольные команды, выполнять которые нужно от разных версий php, есть ли возможность перелинковать `/usr/bin/php7.3` в папке test.project на просто `php` и естественно чтобы в каталоге test.project2 `php` было версией 8 и т.д. Можно ли такое реализовать на линуксе?

Comment: В вашей ситуации идеальным решением будет использовать Docker.

Comment: Это да, но вопрос не за докер, проектов много и все старые, переносить на докер или писать под каждый контейнер со своими версиям нет времени, и средств.

Comment: Вы не пишете под контейнер, вы образ создаете под ваши нужды. По  факту это не очень много времени. Однако если вы нашли удовлетворяющий вас вариант, это хорошо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется. Создаёте в каждой папке символическую ссылку на нужный бинарник PHP и запускаете либо как `./php` либо просто `php`, добавив `.` в начало `PATH`.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php7.3 <path_to>/test.project/php
ln- s /usr/bin/php8 .<path_to>/test.project2/php
```

Как вы вызываете PHP в скриптах? Если просто как PHP, то команда `PATH=<path_to>/test.project/:$PATH test_script.sh` запустит скрипт с окружением, в котором в переменной PATH первым сегментом будет стоять `test.project`. Поэтому `bash` запустит `php` из  каталога `test.project`, то есть символическую ссылку на тот бинарник, который вам нужен.

Comment: То есть - чтобы была команда такого рода `php scripts`, мне нужно указать сим линку так `ln -s /usr/bin/php7.3 ./var/www/test.project/php`? А точка в начале не укажет Linux что это относительній путь?

Comment: Хм, вот попробовал как-то так https://i.imgur.com/86WLuo9.png не совсем то что нужно, или я Вас не поняв.

Comment: Я ведь не просто так писал про PATH. Попробуйте вот так: `PATH=.:$PATH php -v`

Comment: Да, простите, я не совсем понял про PATH, так работает `PATH=.:$PATH php -v`, но без `PATH=.:$PATH` эффект теряется, я так предполагаю нужно что-то по типу `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir`

Comment: `export` заносит изменения в окружение для всех команд, а `PATH=.:$PATH cmd` меняет переменную только на время выполнения команды `cmd`. Обычно не рекомендуют добавлять `.` в `PATH` из соображений безопасности.